# Can't find onClick method

Tags: android, button

So, I'm getting this error

```
11-15 16:55:40.617: E/AndroidRuntime(316): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ingresarBtnClick(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'ingresarButton'
```

This is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/Login">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="Número de Lecturista" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:inputType="number" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/numLecEditText" android:maxLength="4">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>       
    </EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="PIN"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number" android:password="true" android:id="@+id/pinEditText" android:maxLength="4"></EditText>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ingresar" android:id="@+id/ingresarButton" android:onClick="ingresarBtnClick"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Salir" android:id="@+id/salirButton" android:onClick="salirBtnClick"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/opcionesButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Opciones" android:onClick="opcionesBtnClick" ></Button>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FormaLogin extends Dialog
{
    SisLec sisLec;

    public FormaLogin(SisLec _sisLec)
    {       
        super(_sisLec);     
        sisLec = _sisLec;       
        setTitle("Identificación de Lecturista");
    }

    public void mostrar()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        show();
    }

    public void ingresarBtnClick(View view)
    {
        EditText numLecTxt = (EditText) sisLec.findViewById(R.id.numLecEditText);
        EditText pinTxt = (EditText) sisLec.findViewById(R.id.pinEditText);

        if(numLecTxt.getText().length() > 0)
        {
            if(pinTxt.getText().length() > 0)
            {
                if(numLecTxt.getText().equals("1337"))
                {
                    if(pinTxt.getText().equals("8383"))
                    {
                        //sisLec.frmMantenimiento.mostrar();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    HiloIdentificacion hiloIden = new HiloIdentificacion();
                    hiloIden.identificacion(numLecTxt.getText().toString(), pinTxt.getText().toString());
                }
            }
            else
                sisLec.mensaje("Debe de ingresar su pin");
        }
        else
            sisLec.mensaje("Debe de ingresar su número de Lecturista");
    }

    public void salirBtnClick(View view)
    {
        sisLec.salir();
    }

    public void opcionesBtnClick(View view)
    {
        // TODO: Agregar método que muestre la forma de Opciones
    }

    private class HiloIdentificacion extends Thread
    {
        private String usuario, pass;

        public synchronized void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sisLec.identificacion(usuario, pass);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: Agregar registro de error
            }                   
        }

        public synchronized void identificacion(String _usuario, String _pass)
        {
            usuario = _usuario;
            pass = _pass;
            run();
        }
    }
}
```

The method assigned to the button "ingresarButton", "ingresarBtnClick(View view)" is there, as the Androir documentation suggest http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html but sill I'm getting the error.

Does it has anything to do that i'm showing this layout on a Dialog?

SisLec is my Activity class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

android:onClick in the xml routes the event to the method in the activity. But your method is not in the activity, its in your Dialog class. You'll need to either have your activity forward the call to the instance of the Dialog, or have the dialog code register itself as the onClick listener instead of trying to set it in the layout.

Comment: And i wanted to have my activity class the cleanest possible, having each form/dialog button onlick method on the class of the form/dialog and didnt't wanted to use the OnClickListener seen how easy was to set the Click method

thanks for the answer, couldn't find anyone who stated this

Comment: Actually it routes the function call to the basecontext attached to the layoutinflater that creates it, either way it's kind of hard to tell what the problem is when it's written in 4 different languages.

Answer (score 5):

The onClick method needs to be in the Activity class.

Comment: Thanks, i dont want to convolute the Activity class with each button method, looks like i'll be setting the OnClickLsitener on each button

Answer (score 0):

Try `setContentView(sisLec.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login,null));`

Also read this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html